# Jquery: Removing dynamically generated element when modal confirmation button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example:

```
<body>

    <div class="container">
      <!-- Generated by ajax -->
      <div class="item" id="item_1">
        <span class="remove-item"></span>
      </div>
      <div class="item" id="item_2">
        <span class="remove-item"></span>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="modal" id="removeItemModal">
        <h3>Are you sure you want to remove?</h3>
        <input type="hidden" id= "removeItemIdModalInput">
        <button type="button">Cancel</button>
        <button type="button" id="remove-confirm-btn">Confirm</button>
     </div>

</body>
```

When clicked on the `remove-item` class a modal will be shown with two button `Confirm` and `Cancel` when  user clicks on confirm, remove the whole (parent) item. How can i achieve this??
Here's what i did:

```
$(document).on("click",".remove-item", function (e) {

        var removeProductId = $(this).closest(".item").attr("id");

        // Setting the value in modal's hidden input
        $("#removeItemIdModalInput").val(removeProductId);

        $("removeItemModal").modal('toggle');

    });

$(document).on("click","#remove-confirm-btn", function (e) {

        var removeProductId = $("#removeItemIdModalInput").val();

        $("removeItemModal").modal('toggle');

        // Removing the container div/item
        $(removeProductId).fadeOut(300,function () { $(this).remove();});


    });
```

But It's not working. Why? Is there a better approach?

Comment: The variable `removeProductId` is empty since your `<span>` (on which you bind the action) has no `id`. Use `console.log( variable )` to check in your console if a variable is set, and if so, with what value.

Comment: Just updated my question. Please check now @LinkinTED

Comment: You use `remove_item` in your HTML (with an underscore) and `remove-item` in your Javascript (with a hyphen). Also, `id()` isn't valid, use `attr('id')`

Comment: Fixed but still not working :(.

Comment: please post your update code after removing id()

Comment: Where do you open the modal window? Now you only set the value to the hidden field, but you aren't opening the modal, there is some code missing here...

Comment: ADDED please check @LinkinTED

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what solved my problem:

```
$(document).on("click","#remove-confirm-btn", function (e) {

        var removeProductId = $("#removeItemIdModalInput").val();

        $("removeItemModal").modal('toggle');

        // Changed here
        $("body").find(removeProductId).fadeOut(300,function () { $(this).remove();});


    });
```

Answer (score 0):

[EDIT]
TS wants a modal window, this answer provides an alternative

Instead of a modal window, you can use `confirm()` too.

If that is confirmed, you select the parent of the span, by using `parent()`, fade that element out, and remove. Just like you already had.

Also note that you use `remove-item` and `remove_item` both, I changed it all to `remove_item`

```js
$(document).on("click", ".remove_item", function(e) {
  if(confirm("Do you want to remove this box")) {
    $(this).parent().fadeOut(300, function () { $(this).remove();});
  }
  return;
});
```

```css
#item_1, #item_2 {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 2em;
}

.remove_item {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <!-- Generated by ajax -->
  <div id="item_1">
  Item 1
    <span class="remove_item">remove</span>
  </div>
  <div id="item_2">
  Item 2
    <span class="remove_item">remove</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @LinkinTED . But I need to use the modal.

Comment: Okay, I'll leave the answer in case someone else likes the alternative.